# Prepone Region in SystemVerilog

Tags: system-verilog, vlsi, asic

In **SystemVerilog** simulation, the *prepone* region is one of the several regions in a given time slot. What is the actual purpose of this region? Can anyone explain this with a valid example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *preponed* region is a conceptual name for the state of all signals at the begining of the current time slot. The state of signals in the *preponed* region is by definition identical to the state of the *postponed* region of the previous time slot.

This *preponed* state is used as the sampled value for any signal used in an assertion except the clock. Using these sampling semantics eliminates the possibility of race conditions between the clock and the Boolean expression that is part of an assertion statement.

Answer (score 3):

There are in total 17 regions in SystemVerilog event queue including the PLI regions in which preponed region is one of them.

The actual use of preponed region comes in the context of the *assetions*.***Concurrent assertions are evaluated in the observed region but sampled at the preponed region.***

There is no feedback loop available in the event queue of SystemVerilog either from active regions or from reactive regions which means the preponed region is executed only once and since ***sampled values*** are always associated with a clocking event or expression it needs to be processed first in the preponed region and that too also in the allotted time slot before getting assigned or used in the other regions.

The sampling process is same for both preponed and postponed region as the preponed region gets turn up for the events arrive from the *previous time slot*.